# Phonegap: splash screen is not shown on android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

With my config can not force splash screen to appear for andoroid, maybe someone will advice what can be wrong with ti?

In my config.xml I have folling config for splash screen on android:

```
    <platform name="android">
    <splash gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" height="320" src="res/splash/android/port-ldpi.9.png" width="200" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="land-ldpi" height="200" src="res/splash/android/land-ldpi.9.png" width="320" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" height="480" src="res/splash/android/port-mdpi.9.png" width="320" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="land-mdpi" height="320" src="res/splash/android/land-mdpi.9.png" width="480" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" height="800" src="res/splash/android/port-hdpi.9.png" width="480" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="land-hdpi" height="480" src="res/splash/android/land-hdpi.9.png" width="800" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" height="1280" src="res/splash/android/port-xhdpi.9.png" width="720" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi" height="720" src="res/splash/android/land-xhdpi.9.png" width="1280" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="port-xxhdpi" height="1600" src="res/splash/android/port-xxhdpi.9.png" width="960" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="land-xxhdpi" height="960" src="res/splash/android/land-xxhdpi.9.png" width="1600" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" height="1920" src="res/splash/android/port-xxxhdpi.9.png" width="1280" />
        <splash gap:qualifier="land-xxxhdpi" height="1280" src="res/splash/android/land-xxxhdpi.9.png" width="1920" />
     ...
    </platform>
```

I tried to remove `width` and `height` from config, tried to replace `gap:qualifier` with just `qualifier` or `density`, but it didn't work for me.

If I do just put a signle file:

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/splash/android/splash.9.png" />
```

then splash is shown.

Comment: Do you tried to add a delay to your splash ? ( `SplashScreenDelay` ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: having default `<splash src="res/splash/android/splash.9.png" />` in the list is a MUST. Also notice there SHOULD BE NO `width` or `height` attributes on it.